# How to automatically create a required field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema that looks like this:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
    usernameCanonical: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}}
});


userSchema.pre("save", function () {
    this.usernameCanonical = this.username.toLowerCase();
    return next();  
});
```

I want to be able to create new users by only entering a username, and let usernameCanonical get generated by the model automatically.

```
var user = new User({ 
    username: "EXAMPLE_USERNAME"
});
user.save()
```

When I try to do this I get a validation error from mongoose saying that usernameCanonical is required.

```
Path `usernameCanonical` is required.
```

The problem seems to be that the pre-save hooks get called after validation. I don't want to have to manually add a canonical username every time I save a new user. I also don't want to remove the `required` option from the schema.

Is there some way to get a mongoose model to automatically generate a required field? Adding a default value to the usernameCanonical field in the schema seems to prevent the validation error, but it feels like a hack.

Comment: I think you have identified your own problem here. There should be no need to mark a field as "required" when you never intend to supply a value and you are always going to calculate this in a pre-save hook then it sort of negates the logic. Validating "required" input means exactly what it says.

Comment: try `schema.pre('validate', etc)`

Answer (score 3):

As levi mentioned, you should use the *validate()* hook:

[Save/Validate Hooks](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#order)

Check this working example based on your code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
  usernameCanonical: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}}
});

userSchema.pre('validate', function () {
  if ((this.isNew || this.isModified) && this.username) {
    this.usernameCanonical = this.username.toLowerCase();
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/uniqueTest')
  .then(() => {
    // create two users
    const user1 = new User({ 
      username: 'EXAMPLE_USERNAME-1'
    });
    const user2 = new User({ 
      username: 'EXAMPLE_USERNAME-2'
    });

    return Promise.all([
      user1.save(),
      user2.save()
    ]);
  })
  .then(() => {
    // update username
    return User.findOne({ username: 'EXAMPLE_USERNAME-1' })
      .then((user) => {
        user.username = 'EXAMPLE_USERNAME_UPDATED-1';
        return user.save();
      });
  })
  .then(() => mongoose.connection.close())
  .then(() => console.log('script finished successfully'))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    mongoose.connection.close()
      .then(() => process.exit(1));
  });
```

I hope this helps.